# Calculate $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos 3x}{x^4+x^2+1} dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Calculate $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos 3x}{x^4+x^2+1} dx$$

I think that firstly I should use Taylor's theorem, so I have:$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\dots}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$$
However I don't know what I can do the next.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand Taylor's theorem, the denominator does not change in that way...

Comment: No, you are not supposed to use Taylor series here. Most of the terms will lead to divergent integrals. In addition, just as the previous comment said, denominator is not supposed to change. In any case, you need to use residue theorem here

Comment: Exactly as @YuriyS said - residue theorem is required here. The integrand is even, and so we can say ${\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx}$. This screams out for a semi-circle contour

Comment: For a bit more clarity - you cannot always interchange infinite sums and integrals. In this case, we can conclude immediately that you couldn't possibly do this, since for example, ${\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^4}{4!(x^4+x^2+1)}dx}$ will diverge

Comment: Note that $(x^2+1)^2\neq x^4+x^2+1$

Comment: @timofiej8384 Hi! I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Note that $I(a) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin at} {t(t^2+1)}dt
= \frac\pi2 (1-e^{-a}) $, which can be obtain by solving
$$I’’(a)-I(a) = -\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin at}t dt= -\frac\pi2$$

Then
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos 3x}{x^4+x^2+1} dx
= &\frac14\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
 \overset{x=\frac{\sqrt3}2 t-\frac12}{\frac{(1+x)\cos 3x}{x^2+x+1}} +\overset{x= \frac{\sqrt3}2 t +\frac12}{\frac{(1-x)\cos 3x}{x^2-x+1}} d x\\
=& \frac1{\sqrt3}\cos\frac3{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \frac {3\sqrt3}{2}t}{t^2+1} dt + \sin\frac3{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t\sin\frac {3\sqrt3}{2}t}{t^2+1} dt \\
=& \frac1{\sqrt3}\cos\frac3{2}\cdot I’(\frac {3\sqrt3}{2})
-\sin\frac3{2}\cdot I’’(\frac {3\sqrt3}{2})\\
=&\frac\pi2 e^{-\frac {3\sqrt3}{2} }\left( \frac1{\sqrt3}\cos\frac32+ \sin\frac32\right)
  =\frac\pi{\sqrt3}e^{-\frac {3\sqrt3}{2} }\sin\left(\frac\pi6+\frac32\right)
\end{align}

Comment: What an elegant answer!

Comment: I just wonder how you can think such a magical solution!

Answer (score 10):

We seek to evaluate

$$J = \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(3x)}{x^4+x^2+1} \; dx
= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty 
\frac{\cos(3x)}{x^4+x^2+1} \; dx.$$

Following the hint by @MarkViola we observe that
$\sin(3x)/(x^4+x^2+1)$ is odd hence we have

$$J = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty 
\frac{\cos(3x)+i\sin(3x)}{x^4+x^2+1} \; dx
= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty 
\frac{\exp(3ix)}{x^4+x^2+1} \; dx
= \frac{1}{2} K.$$

Introduce

$$f(z) = \frac{\exp(3iz)}{z^4+z^2+1}.$$

We  integrate $f(z)$  along a  contour  consisting of  a line  segment
$\Gamma_0$  from $-R$  to  $R$ on  the real  axis  and a  semicircular
contour $\Gamma_1$ in the upper half plane connecting $R$ to $-R$ with
a counterclockwise  arc of radius  $R$. In the limit  $\Gamma_0$ gives
the integral $K.$ For $\Gamma_1$ we apply the ML bound to get

$$\pi R \times \frac{|\exp(3iR\cos\theta-3R\sin\theta)|}{R^4-R^2-1}
\le \frac{\pi R}{R^4-R^2-1} \rightarrow 0
\quad \text{as} \quad R\rightarrow \infty$$

since  $|\exp(3iR\cos\theta)|=1$  and  $\exp(-3R\sin\theta)  \le  1$
where $0\le\theta\le\pi$ and $z=R\exp(i\theta).$

Now note that

$$w^2+w+1 = \frac{w^3-1}{w-1}$$

so the polynomial in $w$ has roots $\exp(2\pi i k/3)$ where $k=1,2.$
Hence the poles of $f(z)$ are at

$$\exp(2\pi i k/6 + 2\pi i j/2)
= \exp(2\pi i k/6 +  \pi i j) = \pm \exp(\pi i k/3).$$

Restricting to  the upper half plane we get with
$$\rho_0 = \exp(\pi i/3) 
= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3} i
\quad\text{and}\quad
\rho_1 = \exp(2\pi i/3) 
= - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3} i$$

that

$$K = 2\pi i \times \mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_0} f(z)
+ 2\pi i \times \mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_1} f(z).$$

Since $K$ is a real number this becomes

$$K = - 2\pi \times \Im(\mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_0} f(z))
- 2\pi \times \Im(\mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_1} f(z)).$$

As both poles are simple we find that

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_{0,1}} f(z) 
= \frac{\exp(3i\rho_{0,1})}{4\rho_{0,1}^3+2\rho_{0,1}}.$$

so that

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_0} f(z) 
= \frac{\exp(3i\rho_0)}{2\rho_0-4}
= \exp\left(\frac{3}{2} i - \frac{3}{2} \sqrt{3}\right)
\frac{1}{-3+\sqrt{3} i} 
\\ = \exp\left(\frac{3}{2} i - \frac{3}{2} \sqrt{3}\right)
\frac{-3-\sqrt{3}i}{12}
\\ = \frac{1}{12} \exp\left(-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{3}\right)
\exp\left(\frac{3}{2} i\right)(-3-\sqrt{3}i)$$

and

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_1} f(z) 
= \frac{\exp(3i\rho_1)}{2\rho_1+4}
= \exp\left(-\frac{3}{2} i - \frac{3}{2} \sqrt{3}\right)
\frac{1}{3+\sqrt{3} i}
\\ = \exp\left(-\frac{3}{2} i - \frac{3}{2} \sqrt{3}\right)
\frac{3-\sqrt{3}i}{12}
\\ = \frac{1}{12} \exp\left(-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{3}\right)
\exp\left(-\frac{3}{2} i\right)(3-\sqrt{3}i).$$

This gives

$$K = - 2\pi 
\frac{1}{12} \exp\left(-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{3}\right) 
\\ \times
(\cos(3/2) \times (-\sqrt{3}) + \sin(3/2) \times (-3)
+ \cos(-3/2) \times (-\sqrt{3}) + \sin(-3/2) \times 3)
\\ = - \pi 
\frac{1}{6} \exp\left(-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{3}\right) 
\\ \times
(- \cos(3/2) \sqrt{3} - \sin(3/2) \times 3
- \cos(3/2) \sqrt{3} - \sin(3/2) \times 3).$$

With $J = \frac{1}{2} K$ we find at last

$$\frac{\pi}{6}
\exp\left(-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{3}\right)
\left(\cos\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\times\sqrt{3}
+\sin\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\times 3\right).$$

Following the work by @Quanto this becomes

$$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}
\exp\left(-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{3}\right)
\left(\cos\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\times\frac{1}{2}
+\sin\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\times\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right).$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}
\exp\left(-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{3}\right)
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{3}{2}\right).}$$

Comment: +1 Neatly explained

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=\frac{\cos(3x)}{x^4+x^2+1}$.  Inasmuch as $f$ is an even function, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(3x)}{x^4+x^2+1}\,dx&=\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i3x}}{x^4+x^2+1}\,dx\\\\
&=\pi i \left(\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{i3z}}{z^4+z^2+1}, z=e^{i\pi/3}\right)+\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{i3z}}{z^4+z^2+1}, z=e^{i2\pi/3}\right)\right)
\end{align}$$

where we have used the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).

Can you finish now?

Comment: @timofiej8384 Hi! I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)